# How to open a page and activate specific JS?

Tags: javascript, jplayer, cross-site

I have a jplayer on a website, which embeds [several playlists](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/).
To activate these playlists, I use this function :

```
jQuery("#playlist_french_baroque").click(function() {
...
});
```

This works very well.

Now, on other pages on the same website I want to load a specific playlist.
This doesn't work because I use the click() function.

What should I do for that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your /listen page add this code

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $(window.location.hash).click();
    }
});
```

This will execute when the page loads, and check if the hash has been set then call the click hander on the element with that hash.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to load something without user intervention, you can use the `.ready()` method provided by jQuery (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // do whatever you need
});
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$(function() {
 // do whatever you need
});
```

The code is executed after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was to activate the playlist externally (by the hash for example).